# How to combine mutually exclusive columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with multiple mutually exclusive columns in it (don't ask me why, somebody created it like that. *sigh*). Below is an example of it.

```
-------------------------------------------
| ID | BLACK | WHITE | RED | GREEN | BLUE |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1     | 0     | 0   | 0     | 0    |
-------------------------------------------
| 2  | 0     | 0     | 1   | 0     | 0    |
-------------------------------------------
| 3  | 0     | 1     | 0   | 0     | 0    |
-------------------------------------------
```

well you get the idea, it contains thousands of record. Now, how do I combine it into a single "COLOR" column. Like below.

```
--------------
| ID | COLOR |
--------------
| 1  | BLACK |
--------------
| 2  | RED   |
--------------
| 3  | WHITE |
--------------
```

all I can think of right now is to do 5 of these

```
UPDATE table SET COLOR = 'BLACK' WHERE BLACK = 1
```

oh I forgot to mention, the table that I am currently working on contains **at least** 15 mutually exclusive columns! are there any simpler ways I can do this?

**Edit**
changed COLORS to COLOR

Comment: Are you sure an ID can have only one color? The fact that you called the column `COLORS` seems to indicate that more than one is a possibility.

Comment: oops. sorry. it's suppose to be COLOR.. haha.. got confused there.

Comment: If ever a problem was crying out for normalisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `case-expression`, as in this abbreviated example:

```
update table
  set color= 
    case
      when black then "black"
      when red   then "red"
      when blue  then "blue"
    end;
```

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/858cbe/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

A solution is:

Create a definition table that have three column(id int,color string,mutual string) and name it tbl_color then fill this table manualy like this:

```
--------------
| ID   | COLOR | mutual
--------------
| 101  | BLACK | 10000
--------------
| 102  | RED   | 00100
--------------
| 103  | WHITE | 01000
| 104  | green | 00010
| 105  | blue  | 00001
--------------
```

Then join your table with this table and insert result to new table:

```
Insert into new_table
Select t1.id,t2.color from old_table t1 join tbl_color t2
on(t2.mutual=concat(black,white,red,green,blue));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ifs can be done, it is a bit hard to read, there might be a better solution but that would work...

```
UPDATE table SET COLOR =
   IF(BLACK=1,'BLACK',
       IF(WHITE=1,'WHITE',
           IF(RED=1,'RED',
               ...
           )
       )
   )
```